# Vim keeps putting in "*" on new lines

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

So I keep running into this problem when I'm working in CSS.

I'll enter in "*" to reset the HTML, but I'll hit enter and I'll end up getting something that looks like this:

```
* {
    *
    *}
```

I have a plugin that automatically completes my brackets but I know it's not that causing it.

Is there any setting I can change that will make that stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable that feature with this command:

```
:set formatoptions-=r
```

See `:help fo-table`.

NOTE: this actually changes Vim's behaviour when writing comments, which may or may not be an acceptable trade-off.

If you want that setting to be applied automatically every time you edit a `css` file you can add these line to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup css
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType css set formatoptions-=r
augroup END
```

Alternatively, you can put that line:

```
set formatoptions-=r
```

in that file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim
```

Comment: Ideally, one would set `comments` appropriately in CSS files as well, and use `set local` to each buffer.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, what value would you recommend for `comments` (which is buffer-local by default anyway, like `formatoptions`)?

Comment: I've no idea what the comment syntax for CSS is.